# Get exact count using given Key:value Payers form JSON using javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geojson

I have a Geojson which is generating automatically using Leaflet.

```
var myGeometry = JSON.stringify({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "178",
        "name": "178_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Garbage",
        "Comment": "",
        "Photo": "IMG_20170712_122714.jpg",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Duration": "5 Days",
        "Composition": "Organic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-12",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.84118652343751,
          22.550610920226646
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "131",
        "name": "131_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Carcass",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "Onroad",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.88787841796876,
          22.872379306788158
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "157",
        "name": "157_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sewer",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Matters": "Water",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.60498046875,
          22.667244265664948
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "187",
        "name": "187_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Manhole",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Matters": "Water",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.97851562500001,
          22.563293244707797
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "212",
        "name": "212_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Septic_Tank",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Matters": "Wastes",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.3468017578125,
          22.715390019335942
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "239",
        "name": "239_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Drains",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Other",
        "Matters": "Other",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.68463134765625,
          22.930571229938142
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "264",
        "name": "264_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Ponds",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Semi_dry",
        "Near_Si": "",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Situation": "Dirty"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.43194580078125,
          22.821757357861237
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "120",
        "name": "120_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Ceremonial_house",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "Night_time",
        "Nature": "Loud_speaker",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.14880371093751,
          22.705255477207526
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "150",
        "name": "150_marker",
        "Data_name": "Dog House",
        "Fac_type": "Animal_sheds",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Uncleaned",
        "Duration": "5 Days",
        "Nature": "Dog",
        "Nearness": "Y",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "444"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.10485839843751,
          22.902743425252357
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "260",
        "name": "260_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Hooking",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Domestic",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.50860595703126,
          22.690052257634015
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "285",
        "name": "285_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Mobile_tower",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_ground",
        "Duration": "",
        "Service_provider": "",
        "Count": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.31909179687501,
          22.844539566770546
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "310",
        "name": "310_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Mela",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nearness": "",
        "Purpose": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.31085205078126,
          23.006436171834565
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "335",
        "name": "335_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Urinal",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Potted",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Domestic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Nearness": "rrrrr"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.98950195312501,
          23.01402032323799
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "363",
        "name": "363_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Spitting",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_road_side",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Domestic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.14056396484376,
          23.049407390110577
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "396",
        "name": "396_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sound_Morning",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Human": "Yes",
        "Vehicle": "Bi_cycle",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.50311279296876,
          22.842008398595794
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "425",
        "name": "425_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sound_Noon",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Human": "Yes",
        "Vehicle": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.79449462890625,
          22.996323306867165
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "450",
        "name": "450_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sound_Afternoon",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Human": "Yes",
        "Vehicle": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.98675537109375,
          22.72805714175105
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "475",
        "name": "475_marker",
        "Data_name": "Abonormal",
        "Fac_type": "Odour",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.77252197265625,
          22.72299043351299
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "500",
        "name": "500_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Smoke",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Origin": "Industrial",
        "Colour": "Black",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.58026123046875,
          22.80909892750663
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "525",
        "name": "525_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Waterlogging",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_road",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Leakege",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.52258300781251,
          22.98873816096074
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "178",
        "name": "178_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Garbage",
        "Comment": "",
        "Photo": "IMG_20170712_115610.jpg",
        "Situation": "Dispersed",
        "Duration": "5 Days",
        "Composition": "Organic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-12",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.65716552734376,
          22.497332432882345
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "292",
        "name": "292_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Canal",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Stagnant",
        "Duration": "2 Days",
        "Nature": "Hydrophytic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Near_Si": "y"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.25042724609376,
          22.525242774383898
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "288",
        "name": "288_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Stream",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Slugged",
        "Duration": "2 Days",
        "Nature": "Clean",
        "Nearness": "y",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.00073242187501,
          22.461802035333992
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "228",
        "name": "228_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Bushes",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_land",
        "Situation": "Cleaned",
        "Duration": "2 days",
        "Nature": "y",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.39624023437501,
          22.53285370752713
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "197",
        "name": "197_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Trees",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "Other",
        "Situation": "Canopy",
        "Duration": "1 Day",
        "Nature": "n",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.1103515625,
          22.545537663981865
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "210",
        "name": "210_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Excavation",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "On_the_road",
        "Duration": "1 Day",
        "Nature": "Construction",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.87139892578126,
          22.471954507739227
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "243",
        "name": "243_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Blockage",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_ground",
        "Duration": "2 Days",
        "Nature": "Repair",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.0059814453125,
          22.461802035333992
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

In this geojson there some attributes which are predefined by me and I want to Know specific count of that Attribute by given “key==Value and Key== value” like simple query we do in MySQL.

I want this using Javascript and/ or JQuery .

```
    var count = 0;
for (var k in myGeometry) {
    if (myGeometry.hasOwnProperty("'Situation': 'Open', 'Fac_type': 'Garbage'")) {
       ++count;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Please Guide me how can I make this work.

I want to query using two value or using tow payers of Key=value.

**Example:**

```
Total = count ("Fac_type": "Garbage","Situation": "Open")
```

or

```
count ("Garbage" and "Open")
```

Answer will be 2 because there are two **Situation = Open where Fac_type = Garbage.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this **count()** function

```js
function count(myGeometry) {
myGeometry=$.parseJSON(myGeometry);
var count=0;
$.each(myGeometry.features,function () {
    if(this.properties.Fac_type=="Garbage" && this.properties.Situation=="Open"){
        count++
    }
});
alert(count);
console.log(count);
}
var myGeometry = JSON.stringify({
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "178",
            "name": "178_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Garbage",
            "Comment": "",
            "Photo": "IMG_20170712_122714.jpg",
            "Situation": "Open",
            "Duration": "5 Days",
            "Composition": "Organic",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-12",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.84118652343751,
                22.550610920226646
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "131",
            "name": "131_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Carcass",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "Onroad",
            "Situation": "Open",
            "Duration": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.88787841796876,
                22.872379306788158
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "157",
            "name": "157_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Sewer",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Open",
            "Matters": "Water",
            "Duration": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.60498046875,
                22.667244265664948
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "187",
            "name": "187_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Manhole",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Open",
            "Matters": "Water",
            "Duration": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.97851562500001,
                22.563293244707797
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "212",
            "name": "212_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Septic_Tank",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Open",
            "Matters": "Wastes",
            "Duration": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.3468017578125,
                22.715390019335942
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "239",
            "name": "239_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Drains",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Other",
            "Matters": "Other",
            "Duration": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.68463134765625,
                22.930571229938142
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "264",
            "name": "264_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Ponds",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Nature": "Semi_dry",
            "Near_Si": "",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": "",
            "Situation": "Dirty"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.43194580078125,
                22.821757357861237
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "120",
            "name": "120_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Ceremonial_house",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "Night_time",
            "Nature": "Loud_speaker",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.14880371093751,
                22.705255477207526
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "150",
            "name": "150_marker",
            "Data_name": "Dog House",
            "Fac_type": "Animal_sheds",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Uncleaned",
            "Duration": "5 Days",
            "Nature": "Dog",
            "Nearness": "Y",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": "444"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.10485839843751,
                22.902743425252357
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "260",
            "name": "260_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Hooking",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Nature": "Domestic",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.50860595703126,
                22.690052257634015
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "285",
            "name": "285_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Mobile_tower",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "On_the_ground",
            "Duration": "",
            "Service_provider": "",
            "Count": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.31909179687501,
                22.844539566770546
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "310",
            "name": "310_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Mela",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Nearness": "",
            "Purpose": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.31085205078126,
                23.006436171834565
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "335",
            "name": "335_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Urinal",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Potted",
            "Duration": "",
            "Nature": "Domestic",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": "",
            "Nearness": "rrrrr"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.98950195312501,
                23.01402032323799
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "363",
            "name": "363_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Spitting",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "On_the_road_side",
            "Situation": "Open",
            "Duration": "",
            "Nature": "Domestic",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.14056396484376,
                23.049407390110577
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "396",
            "name": "396_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Sound_Morning",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Human": "Yes",
            "Vehicle": "Bi_cycle",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": "",
            "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.50311279296876,
                22.842008398595794
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "425",
            "name": "425_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Sound_Noon",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Human": "Yes",
            "Vehicle": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": "",
            "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.79449462890625,
                22.996323306867165
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "450",
            "name": "450_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Sound_Afternoon",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Human": "Yes",
            "Vehicle": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": "",
            "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.98675537109375,
                22.72805714175105
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "475",
            "name": "475_marker",
            "Data_name": "Abonormal",
            "Fac_type": "Odour",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.77252197265625,
                22.72299043351299
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "500",
            "name": "500_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Smoke",
            "Photo": "",
            "Duration": "",
            "Origin": "Industrial",
            "Colour": "Black",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.58026123046875,
                22.80909892750663
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "525",
            "name": "525_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Waterlogging",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "On_the_road",
            "Duration": "",
            "Nature": "Leakege",
            "Collection_Date": "",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.52258300781251,
                22.98873816096074
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "178",
            "name": "178_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Garbage",
            "Comment": "",
            "Photo": "IMG_20170712_115610.jpg",
            "Situation": "Dispersed",
            "Duration": "5 Days",
            "Composition": "Organic",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-12",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.65716552734376,
                22.497332432882345
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "292",
            "name": "292_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Canal",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Stagnant",
            "Duration": "2 Days",
            "Nature": "Hydrophytic",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": "",
            "Near_Si": "y"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.25042724609376,
                22.525242774383898
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "288",
            "name": "288_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Stream",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "Slugged",
            "Duration": "2 Days",
            "Nature": "Clean",
            "Nearness": "y",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.00073242187501,
                22.461802035333992
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "228",
            "name": "228_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Bushes",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "On_land",
            "Situation": "Cleaned",
            "Duration": "2 days",
            "Nature": "y",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.39624023437501,
                22.53285370752713
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "197",
            "name": "197_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Trees",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "Other",
            "Situation": "Canopy",
            "Duration": "1 Day",
            "Nature": "n",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.1103515625,
                22.545537663981865
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "210",
            "name": "210_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Excavation",
            "Photo": "",
            "Situation": "On_the_road",
            "Duration": "1 Day",
            "Nature": "Construction",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                87.87139892578126,
                22.471954507739227
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": "243",
            "name": "243_marker",
            "Fac_type": "Blockage",
            "Photo": "",
            "Location": "On_the_ground",
            "Duration": "2 Days",
            "Nature": "Repair",
            "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
            "Remarks": ""
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                88.0059814453125,
                22.461802035333992
            ]
        }
    }
]
});

count(myGeometry);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank your for your urgent help, I am making little change in your code  :)

function count(Geometry, factype, situation) {
Geojson=$.parseJSON(Geometry);
var count=0;
$.each(Geojson.features,function () {
    if(this.properties.Fac_type==factype && this.properties.Situation==situation){
        count++
    }
});
alert(count);
console.log(count);
}
count(myGeometry, 'Garbage', 'Open');

Comment: Yes, This is what I am looking for. thank you very much.

Comment: @KuntalParbat you are welcome and please close your question by accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `JSON.stringify` if you want to traverse your JSON object and use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) like,

```
var count = 0;
$.each(myGeometry.features, function(k, v) {
  var p = v.properties || null;
  if (p.hasOwnProperty("Situation") && p.Situation == 'Open' && p.hasOwnProperty("Fac_type") && p.Fac_type == 'Garbage') {
    ++count;
  }
});
```

Snippet,

```js
var myGeometry = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "178",
        "name": "178_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Garbage",
        "Comment": "",
        "Photo": "IMG_20170712_122714.jpg",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Duration": "5 Days",
        "Composition": "Organic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-12",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.84118652343751,
          22.550610920226646
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "131",
        "name": "131_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Carcass",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "Onroad",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.88787841796876,
          22.872379306788158
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "157",
        "name": "157_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sewer",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Matters": "Water",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.60498046875,
          22.667244265664948
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "187",
        "name": "187_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Manhole",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Matters": "Water",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.97851562500001,
          22.563293244707797
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "212",
        "name": "212_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Septic_Tank",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Matters": "Wastes",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.3468017578125,
          22.715390019335942
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "239",
        "name": "239_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Drains",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Other",
        "Matters": "Other",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.68463134765625,
          22.930571229938142
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "264",
        "name": "264_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Ponds",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Semi_dry",
        "Near_Si": "",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Situation": "Dirty"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.43194580078125,
          22.821757357861237
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "120",
        "name": "120_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Ceremonial_house",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "Night_time",
        "Nature": "Loud_speaker",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.14880371093751,
          22.705255477207526
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "150",
        "name": "150_marker",
        "Data_name": "Dog House",
        "Fac_type": "Animal_sheds",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Uncleaned",
        "Duration": "5 Days",
        "Nature": "Dog",
        "Nearness": "Y",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "444"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.10485839843751,
          22.902743425252357
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "260",
        "name": "260_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Hooking",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Domestic",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.50860595703126,
          22.690052257634015
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "285",
        "name": "285_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Mobile_tower",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_ground",
        "Duration": "",
        "Service_provider": "",
        "Count": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.31909179687501,
          22.844539566770546
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "310",
        "name": "310_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Mela",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nearness": "",
        "Purpose": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.31085205078126,
          23.006436171834565
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "335",
        "name": "335_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Urinal",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Potted",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Domestic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Nearness": "rrrrr"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.98950195312501,
          23.01402032323799
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "363",
        "name": "363_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Spitting",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_road_side",
        "Situation": "Open",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Domestic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.14056396484376,
          23.049407390110577
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "396",
        "name": "396_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sound_Morning",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Human": "Yes",
        "Vehicle": "Bi_cycle",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.50311279296876,
          22.842008398595794
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "425",
        "name": "425_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sound_Noon",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Human": "Yes",
        "Vehicle": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.79449462890625,
          22.996323306867165
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "450",
        "name": "450_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Sound_Afternoon",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Human": "Yes",
        "Vehicle": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Magnitude_in_DB": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.98675537109375,
          22.72805714175105
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "475",
        "name": "475_marker",
        "Data_name": "Abonormal",
        "Fac_type": "Odour",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.77252197265625,
          22.72299043351299
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "500",
        "name": "500_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Smoke",
        "Photo": "",
        "Duration": "",
        "Origin": "Industrial",
        "Colour": "Black",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.58026123046875,
          22.80909892750663
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "525",
        "name": "525_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Waterlogging",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_road",
        "Duration": "",
        "Nature": "Leakege",
        "Collection_Date": "",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.52258300781251,
          22.98873816096074
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "178",
        "name": "178_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Garbage",
        "Comment": "",
        "Photo": "IMG_20170712_115610.jpg",
        "Situation": "Dispersed",
        "Duration": "5 Days",
        "Composition": "Organic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-12",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.65716552734376,
          22.497332432882345
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "292",
        "name": "292_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Canal",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Stagnant",
        "Duration": "2 Days",
        "Nature": "Hydrophytic",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": "",
        "Near_Si": "y"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.25042724609376,
          22.525242774383898
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "288",
        "name": "288_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Stream",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "Slugged",
        "Duration": "2 Days",
        "Nature": "Clean",
        "Nearness": "y",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.00073242187501,
          22.461802035333992
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "228",
        "name": "228_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Bushes",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_land",
        "Situation": "Cleaned",
        "Duration": "2 days",
        "Nature": "y",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.39624023437501,
          22.53285370752713
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "197",
        "name": "197_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Trees",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "Other",
        "Situation": "Canopy",
        "Duration": "1 Day",
        "Nature": "n",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.1103515625,
          22.545537663981865
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "210",
        "name": "210_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Excavation",
        "Photo": "",
        "Situation": "On_the_road",
        "Duration": "1 Day",
        "Nature": "Construction",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          87.87139892578126,
          22.471954507739227
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "243",
        "name": "243_marker",
        "Fac_type": "Blockage",
        "Photo": "",
        "Location": "On_the_ground",
        "Duration": "2 Days",
        "Nature": "Repair",
        "Collection_Date": "2017-07-13",
        "Remarks": ""
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          88.0059814453125,
          22.461802035333992
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

var count = 0;
$.each(myGeometry.features, function(k, v) {
  var p = v.properties || null;
  console.log(p.Situation, p.Fac_type);
  if (p.hasOwnProperty("Situation") && p.Situation == 'Open' && p.hasOwnProperty("Fac_type") && p.Fac_type == 'Garbage') {
    ++count;
  }
});
console.log('Total open garages are: ' + count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```